# great_expectations: The command checkpoint does not exist

Tags: python

Проблема при работе с great_expectations.

установлена версия great_expectations==0.13.43. пробую использовать команду `great_expectations checkpoint new`, получаю результат, что

> The command checkpoint does not exist. Please use one of:
> ['checkpoint', 'datasource', 'docs', 'init', 'project', 'store',
> 'suite', 'validation_operator']

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понял, это было какая-то глобальная проблема данной версии из-за недостающих зависимостей. Решилось после установки дополнительно nbformat==5.4.0